# No login required on Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-roo

What i have to do to not require login on the main page?
this is a part of applicationContext-Security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

Comment: Use `permitAll` for the "main page" URL pattern, whatever that is.

Comment: That was the first thing i try.

Comment: Why doesn't your question have it? Unless you provide more information - the URL, the actual configuration you used and the log output, it will be difficult to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
<http pattern="/home" security='none' />
```

put it same level with your  tag

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" /> <!-- new -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" /> <!-- new -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

The intercep-url evaluates in order and use the first matching permission. So, if you add the "/index" and "/" pattern before "/**" this match will be applied.